# CSV to object model mapping

Tags: c#, linq, csv

I have a CSV file that I want to read into a List.  Here's an example file:

```
Plant,Material,"Density, Lb/ft3",Storage Location
FRED,10000477,64.3008,3300
FRED,10000479,62.612,3275
FRED,10000517,90,3550
FRED,10000517,72,3550
FRED,10000532,90,3550
FRED,10000532,72,3550
FRED,10000550,97,3050
```

I know I can manually read in the CSV file and build the list using a normal StreamReader, but I was wondering if there was a better way, perhaps using LINQ?

Comment: To a list of what? Do you have a class for that already? Is anonymous type okay?

Comment: I have a class that represents the data in the csv.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You can use a simple code like this, which ignores the header and doesn't work with quotes, but may be sufficient for your needs.

```
from line in File.ReadAllLines(fileName).Skip(1)
let columns = line.Split(',')
select new
{
  Plant = columns[0],
  Material = int.Parse(columns[1]),
  Density = float.Parse(columns[2]),
  StorageLocation = int.Parse(columns[3])
}
```

Or you can use a library, like others suggested.

Comment: @terphi That would require using quotes and like I said, my code won't work with that.

Comment: Sorry, guess I was skimming.

Answer (score 43):

For the specific data shown in your question...

```
var yourData = File.ReadAllLines("yourFile.csv")
                   .Skip(1)
                   .Select(x => x.Split(','))
                   .Select(x => new
                                {
                                    Plant = x[0],
                                    Material = x[1],
                                    Density = double.Parse(x[2]),
                                    StorageLocation = int.Parse(x[3])
                                });
```

If you already have a type declared for your data then you can use that rather than the anonymous type.

Note that this code isn't robust *at all*. It won't correctly handle values containing commas/newlines etc, quoted string values, or any of the other esoteric stuff that is often found in CSV files.

Comment: I'm trying to figure out a way where the columns: Plant, Material .... can be defined at runtime, any solution?

Answer (score 6):

There's a codeproject for that:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/linq/LINQtoCSV.aspx

However, you may want to look here:

[Linq and streamreader getting lines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2320122/linq-and-streamreader-getting-lines)

Answer (score 6):

I wrote a simple library to allow developers to use LINQ on CSV files. Here is my blog post about it: http://procbits.com/2010/10/11/using-linq-with-csv-files/

In your case, you would have to change your header string to look like this:

```
Plant,Material,DensityLbft3,StorageLocation
```

And then you could parse the file like this:

```
var linqCSV = new CsvToXml("csvfile", true);
linqCsv.TextQualifier = null;

linqCsv.ColumnTypes.Add("Plant", typeof(string));
linqCsv.ColumnTypes.Add("Material", typeof(int));
linqCsv.ColumnTypes.Add("DensityLbft3", typeof(double));
linqCsv.ColumnTypes.Add("StorageLocation", typeof(int));

linqCsv.Convert();
```

You could then use LINQ like this:

```
var items = from item in linqCsv.DynamicRecords
            where item.Plant == "Fred" && item.DensityLbft3 >= 62.6
            orderby item.StorageLocation
            select item;
```

Hope that helps or works for you.

Answer (score 1):

With [Cinchoo ETL](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ChoETL/) library, can parse CSV file into objects

Define type matching CSV file structure as below

```
public class PlantType
{
    public string Plant { get; set; }
    public int Material { get; set; }
    public double Density { get; set; }
    public int StorageLocation { get; set; }
}
```

Load the CSV file

```
static void LoadCSV()
{
    using (var p = new ChoCSVReader<PlantType>("*** YOUR CSV FILE PATH ***")
        .WithFirstLineHeader(true)
        )
    {
        foreach (var rec in p)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(rec.Dump());
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't use LINQ but [CsvHelper](https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/) is a simple method to implement CSV parsing to a .NET object:

```
using (TextReader txt = new StreamReader(filename))
{
    using (var csv = new CsvReader(txt))
    {
        var records = csv.GetRecords<PlantMaterial>();
        return records.ToList();
    }
}
```