# Generate JSON Array from CSV or Database

Tags: asp.net, arrays, json, web-services, csv

I am looking to create a JSON array from a CSV or Database. How would I format my source data or does anyone have advice/links to tutorials for either creating a .NET Web Service or another method to generate JSON from a CSV or database? An example array is below.

Example:

```
{
section1: [
{
"id":1,
"title":mytitle1
}
],
{
section2: [
{
"id":2,
"title":mytitle2
}
], etc.....
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

function GetImageToJson:string;
    var
      Q,Q1:TSQLQuery;
      content,Liststr : String;
      NextRecord : Integer;
    begin
      content :='[';
      Liststr :='';
      Q := TSQLQuery.Create(nil);
      Q.Database := dmDatabase.IBConnection;
      Q.SQL.Text :=
        'SELECT ID,TB,NAME FROM V_IMAGES';
      Q.Open;
      Q.First;
      NextRecord :=0;
      if not Q.Fields[0].IsNull then begin
        while not Q.eof do begin
           if (NextRecord =1) then
               Liststr :=Liststr +',';
           Liststr := Liststr + '{"ID" : "'  +Q.Fields[0].AsString+'",'+
                                 '"TB" : "'  +Q.Fields[1].AsString+'",'+
                                 '"NAME" : "'+Q.Fields[2].AsString+
                           '"}';
           NextRecord :=1;
           Q.Next;
        end;

```
  end;
  Q.Free;

  Q := TSQLQuery.Create(nil);
  Q.Database := dmDatabase.IBConnection;
  Q.SQL.Text :=
    'SELECT * FROM sETUP';
  Q.Open;
  Q.First;

  if not Q.Fields[0].IsNull then begin
    while not Q.eof do begin
       if (NextRecord =1) then
           Liststr :=Liststr +',';

       Liststr := Liststr + '{"'+Q.Fields[0].DisplayName+'" : "'        +Q.Fields[0].AsString+'",'+
                         '"'+Q.Fields[1].DisplayName+'" : "'  +Q.Fields[1].AsString+'",'+
                         '"'+Q.Fields[2].DisplayName+'" : "'  +Q.Fields[2].AsString+'",'+
                         '"'+Q.Fields[3].DisplayName+'" : "'  +Q.Fields[3].AsString+'",'+
                         '"'+Q.Fields[4].DisplayName+'" : "'  +Q.Fields[4].AsString+'",'+
                         '"'+Q.Fields[5].DisplayName+'" : "'  +Q.Fields[5].AsString+'",'+
                         '"'+Q.Fields[6].DisplayName+'" : "'  +Q.Fields[6].AsString+'",'+
                         '"'+Q.Fields[7].DisplayName+'" : "'  +Q.Fields[7].AsString+'",'+
                         '"TB":"setup"'+
                   '}';

       NextRecord :=1;
       Q.Next;
    end;

  end;
  Q.Free;


  content := content +Liststr+ ']';
  result  := content;

end;
```

Answer (score 1):

I would first convert my csv file to an object, then parse the object to JSON using newtonsoft's json class

[Check this out to learn how to transform CSV to object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3497699/csv-to-object-model-mapping)

[Go here to get newtonsoft's json.net tools (can be done using nuget)](http://json.codeplex.com/)