# Read CSV to list of objects

Tags: c#, csv

I have a CSV file with a listing of varied data(datetime, decimal).  Sample line from CSV:

```
Date,Open,High,Low,Close,Volume,Adj Close  //I need to skip this first line as well
2012-11-01,77.60,78.12,77.37,78.05,186200,78.05
```

I have a list of objects created that I want to read each of the lines into.  The constructor for the objects is below, each of the fields from each CSV line is used and assigned here.

```
    public DailyValues(DateTime date, decimal open, decimal high, decimal low,
        decimal close, decimal volume, decimal adjClose)
        : this()
    {
        Date = date;
        Open = open;
        High = high;
        Low = low;
        Close = close;
        Volume = volume;
        AdjClose = adjClose;
    }

    List<DailyValues> values = new List<DailyValues>();
```

Is there an easy way to read each line of the CSV into my list `values` and appropriately assign each attribute (i.e. date, open, high)?

Comment: There is a `TextFieldParser` class hidden away in the `Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO` namespace. Even though it says VisualBasic, you can use it with C# too.

Comment: I would do this via Linq - see this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3497699/csv-to-object-model-mapping

Comment: @Kevin That doesn't fully conform to the CSV spec. There would be problems if there was any data that contained a comma within the data

Comment: @cost - I completely agree, but looking at the example data I see no problems.

Answer (score 162, accepted):

Why not just parse these explicitly? You have a limited number of properties, so it's not very difficult. Instead of using a constructor requiring many arguments, I used a static method that returns a new `DailyValues` instance as it's return type. This is similar to `DateTime.FromBinary` etc.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.IO;

namespace CsvDemo
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<DailyValues> values = File.ReadAllLines("C:\\Users\\Josh\\Sample.csv")
                                           .Skip(1)
                                           .Select(v => DailyValues.FromCsv(v))
                                           .ToList();
        }
    }

    class DailyValues
    {
        DateTime Date;
        decimal Open;
        decimal High;
        decimal Low;
        decimal Close;
        decimal Volume;
        decimal AdjClose;

        public static DailyValues FromCsv(string csvLine)
        {
            string[] values = csvLine.Split(',');
            DailyValues dailyValues = new DailyValues();
            dailyValues.Date = Convert.ToDateTime(values[0]);
            dailyValues.Open = Convert.ToDecimal(values[1]);
            dailyValues.High = Convert.ToDecimal(values[2]);
            dailyValues.Low = Convert.ToDecimal(values[3]);
            dailyValues.Close = Convert.ToDecimal(values[4]);
            dailyValues.Volume = Convert.ToDecimal(values[5]);
            dailyValues.AdjClose = Convert.ToDecimal(values[6]);
            return dailyValues;
        }
    }
}
```

Of course, you can still add a default constructor, and you will want to add exception handling in case the parsing fails (you can also use `TryParse` for that).

- The `File.ReadAllLines` reads all lines from the CSV file into a string array.
- The `.Skip(1)` skips the header line.
- The `.Select(v => DailyValues.FromCsv(v))` uses Linq to select each line and create a new `DailyValues` instance using the `FromCsv` method. This creates a `System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<CsvDemo.DailyValues>` type.
- Finally, the `.ToList()` convers the `IEnumerable` to a `List` to match the type you want.

Instead of using Linq you could have simply used a `foreach` loop to add each `DailyValues` instance to your list.

Comment: I like this approach, and you could implement more complex CSV parsing in FromCsv if required. +1

Comment: This is much simpler than any other solution provided on stackoverflow :)

Comment: Simple and Effective ! +1

Comment: Isn't in flawed though, what if there was a comma in the actual data, example "Los Angeles, CA" would split across 2 seperate fields. OK if you know the data doesnt contain strings though.

Comment: @Paul: Definitely, but most implementations have different standards to handle comma/special character escaping (i.e. one way is to wrap values containing commas in double quotes, as you said). So you'd probably be better off modifying the logic for those cases when they are known, or using a library that handles CSV parsing instead. My answer assumes the simplest case as described in the question.

Comment: As said before, simple and effective ! +1

Comment: can this be done with a constructor to keep original variables private?

Comment: @Mwspencer Yes, it's fine to use a constructor instead. Please create a new question if you're having a problem with it

Comment: you can acutally leave away the v => DailyValues.FromCsv(v) and just use .Select(DailyValues.FromCsv).ToList(); instead

Comment: @TimGerhard you're right :-) I believe I was trying to be slightly more explicit by using a lambda, in case people were unfamiliar with creating/passing a delegate created from method groups like that

Comment: Probably is not a solution, i'm pretty beginner level! But could be a solution implement the statement `backslash` for correctly escape de comma directly in csv file? --> `"Los Angeles\, CA"`, or you have to check if there are some other value after the first comma encountered