# Import Selected CSV file into New Excel file in user defined order

Tags: c#, .net, excel, csv

I would like to ask for your help!!

I'm trying to import CSV file into New Excel file, User will give the input to select which CSV file, and program should import purticular data into new excel file and data should be in user defined order.

So guide me to choose correct platform or language to do it.
my sample csv
[image]

and my expected output is
[image]

Time string will be Row headers,
VarName will be Column headers.

varvalue will be in main data

Comment: Let me know if you find the answer useful:)

Comment: Hi, I've gone with macro programs to read and write(customized) in new workbook excel. your links are good to read..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many ways to do this. One of flexible ways is:

1. Create a model class for your data. (Each record of your csv file will be an instance of your model)
2. Create a RDLC report that represent your data in your desired layout and format. There you can arrange your data as in rows, columns , pivots, ...
3. Read data from your csv file and fill in List and pass it as data source to your report.
4. Export your report to Excel (and even other supported file formats like .doc, .pdf)

Additional resources:

- [Using a Business Object Data Source with the ReportViewer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms251784.aspx)
- [RDLC-Export directly to Excel or PDF](http://forums.asp.net/post/3830288.aspx)
- [Read csv to list ofobjects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26790477/read-csv-to-list-of-objects)