# How to access a Object property, in a List of generated Objects

Tags: c#, list, object, unity-game-engine

I searched the heck out of it, and i can't solve it.
I have a program setup like this (it's in Unity and Visual Studio 2019 for C#):
Note that the CSV loading goes fine, when i debug the code i can see everything filled with corect data.

```
#region character class
public class _Character
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int Variation { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
#endregion

//Tools.LoadCsv generates a string[,] from a csv file
//Tools.IntParse parses int's with a lot of format error checking

void Start()
    {
#region load characters class
        string[,] CharacterCSV = Tools.LoadCsv(@"Assets/GameDB/character.csv");
        List<_Character> Character = new List<_Character>();
        for (int i = 1; i < CharacterCSV.GetUpperBound(0); i++)
        {
            _Character temp = new _Character();
            temp.Id = Tools.IntParse(CharacterCSV[i, 0]);
            temp.Variation = Tools.IntParse(CharacterCSV[i, 1]);
            temp.Name = CharacterCSV[i, 2];
            temp.LastName = CharacterCSV[i, 3];

            Character.Add(temp);
        }

        CharacterCSV = null;
        #endregion
}
```

I barely understand objects, so i'm sorry if i am doing it wrong.

The questions i have are:

1. Why does the Object List generation Háve to be in Start ? I can't seem to do that in it's own class.
2. How can i get an object from the Character Object List, containing Id = 100 and Name = "John"
   , and access it from another class or method.

I ussualy frankenstein the heck out of code and make it good enough for me, but now i wanted to make something nice and cant seem to get to the objects.

Thanks in advance!

//the major issue was declaring the object inside the class, when declared outside the class, the List Object was available to the outside world.
List<_Character> Character = new List<_Character>(); move to outside Start{}

I'm not editing the question to correct the code, because the question needs to stay clear.
//

Comment: It seems odd you have Start without monobehavior.  If its not a monobehavior you dont have to do it in start

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why does the Object List generation has to be in `Start` ? I can't seem to do that in it's own class.
>
> How can i get an object from the Character Object List, containing Id = 100 and Name = "John" , and access it from another class or method.

If you want to retrieve a character from outside of the class, then, you have to declare the list **outside** of the `Start` function, otherwise, the list will be destroyed since it's a local variable of the function.

```
// Declare the list outside of the functions
private List<_Character> characters;

void Start()
{
    // Avoid using regions, they encourage you to make very long functions with multiple responsabilities, which is not advised
    // Instead, create short and simple functions, and call them
    LoadCharactersFromCSV();
}

void LoadCharactersFromCSV()
{
    string[,] CharacterCSV = Tools.LoadCsv(@"Assets/GameDB/character.csv");

    // If you can, indicate the approximate numbers of elements
    // It's not mandatory, but it improves a little bit the performances
    characters = new List<_Character>( CharacterCSV.GetUpperBound(0) );

    // I believe `i` should start at 0 instead of 1
    for (int i = 1; i < CharacterCSV.GetUpperBound(0); i++)
    {
        // I advise you to create a constructor
        // instead of accessing the properties one by one
        _Character temp = new _Character();
        temp.Id = Tools.IntParse(CharacterCSV[i, 0]);
        temp.Variation = Tools.IntParse(CharacterCSV[i, 1]);
        temp.Name = CharacterCSV[i, 2];
        temp.LastName = CharacterCSV[i, 3];

        characters.Add(temp);
    }

    CharacterCSV = null;
}

// Using this function, you will be able to get a character from its id
public _Character GetCharacter( int id )
{
    for (int 0 = 1; i < characters.Count; i++)
    {
        if( characters[i].Id == id )
            return characters[i];
    }

    // Return null if no character with the given ID has been found
    return null ;
}
```

---

Then, to call `GetCharacter` from another class:

```
public class ExampleMonoBehaviour : MonoBehaviour
{
    // Replace `TheClassName` by the name of the class above, containing the `Start` function
    // Drag & drop in the inspector the gameObject holding the previous class
    public TheClassName CharactersManager;


    // I use `Start` for the sake of the example
    private void Start()
    {
        // According to your code, `_Character` is defined **inside** the other class
        // so you have to use this syntax
        // You can get rid of `TheClassName.` if you declare `_Character` outside of it
        TheClassName._Character john = CharactersManager.GetCharacter( 100 );
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the time you took the answer the question, i'm not at home atm, but i think you answered it perfectly.

Comment: I'm at home now and tested your explanation, it is correct indeed. 
I also added a csvreader Contructor for the Class Object using this excellent stackoverflow example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26790477/read-csv-to-list-of-objects
Sincerely thank you, i can now finish my project. :)

Comment: I am glad my explanation helped you. Please, don't forget to click on the check mark at the left of the answer so as to indicate your problem has been solved. Good luck for the end of your project.