# Marketo - Response of Bulk API serialization

Tags: c#, serialization, json.net, marketo

I'm trying to use the Bulk Import API endpoint within Marketo to fetch the [warnings](https://developers.marketo.com/rest-api/endpoint-reference/lead-database-endpoint-reference/#!/Bulk_Import_Leads/getImportLeadWarningsUsingGET) and [failures](https://developers.marketo.com/rest-api/endpoint-reference/lead-database-endpoint-reference/#!/Bulk_Import_Leads/getImportLeadFailuresUsingGET) associated with a bulk job I [created](https://developers.marketo.com/rest-api/endpoint-reference/lead-database-endpoint-reference/#!/Bulk_Import_Leads/importLeadUsingPOST) within Marketo.

The output of these jobs is stated as an `ObservableOfInputStreamContent`, yet the response of these endpoints returns a csv string (with header column), that's not a JSON object. To compound to this problem, we are using the generated swagger files with the swagger definition file provided by [Marketo](https://developers.marketo.com/rest-api/endpoint-reference/download-swagger-definition/). These generated c# client side files have the `ObservableOfInputStreamContent` object, but it's an empty object. I'm not sure if this is intended, or a mistake on Marketo's side. The generated files will attempt to use `Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ObservableOfInputStreamContent>(responseText, JsonSerializerSettings);` to deserialize the API response to the `ObservableOfInputStreamContent`.

Generated code that deserializes the API response:

```
var responseText = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
try
{
    var typedBody = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(responseText, JsonSerializerSettings);
    return new ObjectResponseResult<T>(typedBody, responseText);
}
catch (Newtonsoft.Json.JsonException exception)
{
    var message = "Could not deserialize the response body string as " + typeof(T).FullName + ".";
    throw new ApiException(message, (int)response.StatusCode, responseText, headers, exception);
}
```

Problem one is that the API does not return JSON to begin with (eg):

```
address,city,country,
123 lane, new york, USA
745 street, new york, USA
```

This call will return this error because of this:

> Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException: Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: a. Path '', line 0, position 0.

The second issue is that  `ObservableOfInputStreamContent` is defined as an empty object to begin with in the generated files. So if the API response was valid JSON, I don't think it would know how to convert to that empty `ObservableOfInputStreamContent` object. The good news about the generated code is that it gives me an option to extend the `ObservableOfInputStreamContent` because it's defined as a `partial` class.

```
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCode("NJsonSchema", "10.1.11.0 (Newtonsoft.Json v11.0.0.0)")]
public partial class ObservableOfInputStreamContent
{

}
```

That said, is there any possible way I can use the `JsonSerializerSettings` to get around this issue? Could I extended the `ObservableOfInputStreamContent` class to hold a string property and then create my own [JsonConverter](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/CustomJsonConverter.htm) to convert the string returned from the API into the new `ObservableOfInputStreamContent`?

Comment: You cannot parse json until all the data is read.  json has open/close tags and the json serializer will fail if you do not have matching open and close tags.

Comment: @jdweng It fails because the response from the API is not JSON at all. There is no open and close tags `{}`.

Comment: The response depends on your URL.  What is your URL?  See : https://developers.marketo.com/rest-api/base-url/

Comment: @jdweng The `BaseUrl` does not alter the response in any way other then pulling in the correct Marketo instance's data. :)

Comment: The URL doesn't contain any parameter (after a question mark)?  Do you have to add any http headers to the post?

Comment: Sorry if I put it confusingly - The request works, it's the response object from those warnings and failures that is different then what is documented by Marketo. The response returns a csv string, while the documentation says it's supposed to be an empty `ObservableOfInputStreamContent` object. I am asking how I can get around this, if I can, using the `JsonSerializerSettings`.

Comment: The format of the response is determined by the request.  So you need to fix the request.

Comment: What does the request look like?

Comment: share the code where you instantiate your request

Comment: why do you have to pass  by `JsonConvert`, why not writing a custom deserializer that parse the csv text reponse like it is done  here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26790477/read-csv-to-list-of-objects?